# Getting directions via MapKit and location services

Tags: objective-c, mapkit, core-location

I am trying to display directions from user location to some destination.  However, when I initiate the directions request I get some error back like this one:

> "The operation couldn’t be completed. (MKLocationErrorDomain error 0.)" UserInfo=0x7f9bc05b1a30 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Turn On Location Services to Allow (null) to Determine Your Location}

Now, evidently it doesn't like the fact that location services are off.  And since my app never launched the pop over that requests permission this makes sense.  However, is there a way to turn on location services using the `MapKit API`?  Must I seriously import `CLLocation` just for that?

Comment: How you are initiating direction request? add that code too

Comment: Are you sure your implementation to get the user location is complete?

Comment: I restarted the simulator and it worked.  It does seem that even if you are using mapKit you must import CoreLocation, get a reference to a location manager, and call the request Authorization method.  Despite the fact that mapView uses its own location manager internally.  Can anyone confirm this?